# How to stop Sublime inserting "#{}" upon writing # inside a string?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I edit a file with syntax = javascript. Entering

```
"bla bla #"
```

automatically transforms to

```
"bla bla #{}"
```

Guess this is integrated handlebars feature or so. Anyway, I seriously mean just "#" when I type it. How can I confiure this?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a built in part of ST. What plugins do you have installed? If you can track down what plugin is causing it, you should probably create an issue for that particular plugin (assuming it's hosted on github or something similar).

Comment: Thx. I have ST 2 and 3 and it occurs only in 3. There I have "Better CoffeeScript", "CoffeeScriptHaml", "PEG.js" packages installed. So I believe it is related to the default js syntax formatted, which is more or less built into ST 3 I guess. I am a ST newbie, so just a guess.

Comment: I'd still lean towards a plugin, but to be sure, try reverting ST [link](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html). Of course, just move the folder so you can move it back later. If it still occurs after reverting, then it is definitely a ST problem rather than a plugin problem. It's definitely a plugin issue. "Better CoffeeScript" has a command that inserts "#{}". Create an issue on that page :) ([link](https://github.com/aponxi/sublime-better-coffeescript/issues))

Comment: you are right, you have been very helpful. could you write a short answer like "disable plugins" and I accept it then? thx so mmuch

Comment: issue reported: https://github.com/aponxi/sublime-better-coffeescript/issues/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see unexpected behavior, you should determine if it is a bug in the editor or a bug with a plugin. To do this, you can revert your install ([link](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/revert.html)). After you have reverted, see if you can reproduce the problem. If you cannot, it is a problem with a plugin. It can be a slow process, but you should enable the plugins one by one to see which causes problem. Based on the plugins you have installed, you can probably make a guess as to which is causing it. I would start with that one.